# Add additional rows in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, tableview, cell

I use Swift 3.
I have UITableView with 7 rows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self        
}

func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
    {        
        return 7
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if (IndexPath.row == 6)
    {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        var index = IndexPath(row: 7, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [index], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)                    
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

I want to add additional cell when I'm scrolling to last cell in table.
But I got this error:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your datasource when you insert or delete any rows from tableView, sot that the number of objects is kept equal to the number of rows in tableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {        
    return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (IndexPath.row == 6) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        var index = IndexPath(row: 7, section: 0)
        let newObject = // create new model object here
        dataSource.insert(newObject, at: 7)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [index], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)                    
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```